# Where in MLB rules does it say batting gloves are legal?

Tags: rules, mlb

If they are legal for batters, then can a pitcher wear a glove on his pitching hand? If the reason for allowing batting gloves is to 'increase the quality of the grip on the bat' then it makes sense for a pitching glove to 'increase the quality of grip on the ball'. I'm sure a batter would agree, because very few batters look forward to an errant cold weather or drizzeld rain, 100 mph baseball heading straight for his . . . . assorted body parts.

Comment: Hi!  I assume from the question text you are asking about Major League Baseball specifically, so I added the tag for you - if you mean baseball more generally, please amend that to the [tag:baseball] tag instead.

Comment: Hi.  You appear to be asking two separate questions.  The title asks where the MLB rule states that batting gloves are legal, the question text discusses "pitching gloves".  We generally try to focus questions more specifically so that there is one "best" answer.  With multiple questions, there may be multiple "best" answers.  Can you please clarify this a bit?  If the question text is accurate, perhaps change the title to ask if pitchers are allowed to wear gloves?

Answer (score 1):

First the legalities:

> *Rule 6.02 (c)(7) Comment:* The pitcher may not attach anything to either hand, any finger out either wrist

Second, pitchers may not want to do it. In Football the quarterback is allowed to wear a glove on their throwing hand and the only player that does that is Teddy Bridgewater.

Third, don’t worry about safety of the batters because most pitchers are using foreign substances anyways. (See what Trevor Bauer has to say about it https://www.sportingnews.com/us/mlb/news/trevor-bauer-mlb-pitchers-steroids-pine-tar/2qhjxr7i4yrq1t15yl99ysvp2)

Comment: Hi!  Can you include a link to the rulebook you quoted that from, for completeness?  Thanks!